# trying to set up a sencond site

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, web-hosting, multiple-sites

I'm having trouble setting up a sencond site on my `apache2` server.
I currently have one site up and running and its even live.
However I have another site I am working on and am trying to host it locally. 
I've created a site-available file named newsite with the following

```
&#60;VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName newsite
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/newsite/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/newsite/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I enable it with `a2ensite` newsite

I edit the host file
127.0.0.1   www.newsite.com

I've run `a2ensite` newsite

Now when I view the new site it works fine,
but when I try view my original site i only get the newsite

If I disable new site (a2dissite newsite) the original site displays fine

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: try clearing ur cache and check

Comment: clear your browser chache and check again. Some time it happens because of old cache file... specially if you are using chrome.

Comment: cool done  but now just just showing the newsite with the new sites css for both sites

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not set your `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives correctly.

For both your virtual hosts, they should be something like this

```
 ServerName newsite.com 
 ServerAlias www.newsite.com 
 ServerName oldsite.com 
 ServerAlias www.oldsite.com
```

What is happening currently is that you have setup a virtual host called newsite. If you do `http://newsite/` : you will see the newsite, however you are doing `www.newsite.com`. Similarly, if you do `http://oldsite/` (assuming it is setup the same way), you will also see oldsite.

When you do `www.newsite.com`, you DNS directs you to the loopback interface, however, when apache gets the request, it doesn't know what to do with it. So it just picks one. This would be no different from if you were to try and access simply by IP.

So solution is either you call `http://newsite/` or fix your `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives.